# Android copy image from gallery folder onto SD Card alternative folder

Tags: android, image, copy, sd-card

I am looking for someone to assist in the code i require in my application to copya image from where they get stored on the HTC desire as standard(the gallery) to a another folder on the SD card. I want the user to be able to click on a button and a certain file is copied from the SD card gallery folder to the another folder on the SD card? Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usmaan,

You can launch the gallery picker intent with the following:

```
    public void imageFromGallery() {
    Intent getImageFromGalleryIntent = 
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(getImageFromGalleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
}
```

When it returns, get the path of the selected image with the following portion of code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            mSelectedImagePath = getPath(data.getData());
            break;
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Now that you have the pathname in a string you can copy it to another location.

Cheers!

EDIT: If you just need to copy a file try something like...

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String sourceImagePath= "/path/to/source/file.jpg";
        String destinationImagePath= "/path/to/destination/file.jpg";
        File source= new File(data, sourceImagePath);
        File destination= new File(sd, destinationImagePath);
        if (source.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Sorry i dont understand, i know hot to take a photo and etc within my application....but later on i want to copy the image from the gallery folder to a different folder,im not sure this code does this does it?

Comment: The first portion of this code will launch you gallery and allow you to select an image.  Once you select the image it will call `onActivityResult()` from the second portion of the code I posted.  It will take the data returned from the gallery app and the `getPath()` function i posted will return to you the full path of the selected image as a String.  This code won't allow you to take a picture with the camera.

Comment: i want to copy the image to a different folder..Also i dont really want to open the gallery, i know the image name already and i know on the sd card it is stored sdcard/dcim/imagename

Comment: looking for somthing that like says copy sdcard/dcim/image.jpg to sdcard/newfolder

Comment: oh...you just need the actual copy?  haha sorry i posted everything leading up to that, sorry ><

Comment: yeh i just want the user to click on button which copies an image from sdcard/dcim folder to just sdcard/newfolder

Comment: Added file copy code of two known files to my original answer

Comment: you may need to do a destination.mkdir() if the destination directory doesn't already exist.  It may not work just cut/paste but its a general outline of a file copy process.

Comment: Try just `File source= new File(souceImagePath);` without the `data` variable

Comment: used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for both and works thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Gallery images are already stored in the SD card in Android phones. The official documentation has a nice section on [working with external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), which you should check out.

Comment: Sorry i was meant to say copy the image from that folder to antoher