# intent ACTION_PICK in specific folder

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i'm need select movie file from folder that located in sd card, in (/sdcard/Movies/FFF)

this what i'm done...

```
Uri data = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getPath());
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null).setDataAndType(data,"video/*");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

but the actual code presents result from all device folders.

i tried those solution, but nothing success
 [Android copy image from gallery folder onto SD Card alternative folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921183/android-copy-image-from-gallery-folder-onto-sd-card-alternative-folder)

[How can I display a specific folder in Android Gallery3D (cooliris)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390402/how-can-i-display-a-specific-folder-in-android-gallery3d-cooliris)

[Gallery with folder filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019534/gallery-with-folder-filter)

in the left pic the Desirable result and in the right pic is what i have done.

[image]

Comment: try using `Uri data = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getPath());
intent = new Intent(Intent. ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(data,"video/*");`

Comment: thanks, but it's doesnt work you suggest to replace ACTION_PICK with ACTION_VIEW. in this result appear "Unsupported File Type" I believe it's expects to receive a file not folder, but I'm not sure